# Replace array value to increment

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this ...

```
[0,0,23,0,0,18,0,0]
```

Then I want to change values ​​that are not '0' (23 & 18) to auto increment, so the end result will be like this,

```
[0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0]
```

is there the best way for all that?
So far this is what I did, but the results were not as expected ... :)

```
<?php

$arr = [0,0,23,0,0,18,0,0];
$x = 1;
$r = collect($arr)->map(function ($value, $key)use($x) {
    if ($value == 0) {
        return $value;
    } else {
        return $x++;
    }
})->all();

dd($r);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us some code!

Comment: If you increment 23, does that not become 24?

Comment: Out of curiosity... what's function collect?

Comment: @dnFer I think it's probably [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-collect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you have your value of `$x` passed into the function via `use`, this isn't allowing the value to be updated.  You need to pass it by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) - `use (&$x)` to allow it to increment the value outside the function...

```
$r = collect($arr)->map(function ($value, $key) use (&$x) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way... Using `foreach` with reference of array `&`

With Passed by Reference

Snippet

```
$arr = [0,0,23,0,0,18,0,0];
$counter = 1;
foreach ($arr as &$val){
   if($val !== 0){
      $val = $counter++;
   }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Note: Be aware of [dangling reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900165/what-is-the-difference-between-garbage-and-dangling-references)

Without reference

Snippet

```
$arr = [0,0,23,0,0,18,0,0];
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val){
       if($val !== 0){
          $arr[$key] = $counter++;
       }
    }
print_r($arr);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
)
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/VVkNZ) 
Pass by reference [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: `$val = $counter++;` or `$val = ++$counter;` saves you a line of code. ;)

Comment: Not when I change your demo.

Comment: @dnFer Link modified demo

Comment: @dnFer Thanks, modified.

Comment: @Progrock look at `foreach`, passed array by reference, that's why array is being altered directly.

Comment: @Progrock Since, OP was forgot to pass by reference, nigel gave correct answer, mine is just minified version. I've linked `Pass By Reference` docs, so OP and other mah learn more about it.

Comment: Safer: `$c = 1; foreach($data as $k => $v) if($v) $data[$k] = $c++;` Beware dangling references: https://3v4l.org/GqC1B

Comment: @Progrock It's reference, Altering actual array without creating temporary array.

Comment: @Progrock I've added your code too! Thanks for letting me know about `Dangling Reference`